# browser session storage persisting in new tabs and windows

Tags: session-storage

every reference I can find assures me that session storage is specific to a browser tab - why is this not happening? I create a new tab - session storage is there. Close the browser window and open a new one - session storage is still there.
MacOS Ventura - Safari, Chrome, Firefox all the same.
And before anyone asks, a) I am not talking about local storage and b) I don’t want to know how to clear it.
I want to know why it isn’t behaving as it should.